# Is there a way to activate NFC during initial phone setup?

Tags: settings, nfc, setup-wizard, android-for-work

My mdm (Ivanti/Landesk) requires to deploy an APK through NFC during the initial phone setup (and only during this setup, where you need to set the langage, time zone, google account, etc.) . 
This is part of the Android Entreprise Device Owner Mode process. ( Some mdm can follow this process with QR codes or afw#codes but mine don't .. )

The thing is the NFC card seems disabled by default at first boot (or after a factory reset), and I can't find a way to either enable it from top quick acess bar or settings pages.

Is there an hidden way to enable some settings at this intial step ?

I'm using Altice S61 in my tests, but I think this may apply to other devices as this is during the android standard setup wizard. ( Android version 8.1 )

Thanks in advance !

Regards

Comment: NFC is a low-speed network with AFAIK max 53KB/sec (424kbit/sec) - are you sure you want to transfer an APK file of several MB using this connection?

Comment: Hello, technically this is not an APK transfer, NFC just pass a link to an APK to download for the device to provision.  
This is described here : https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/prov-devices#nfc_method